# Find a difference equation for $h_r[n]$

Tags: signal-processing

I'm having a signal

\begin{align}
h_r[n] &= r^n \sin\Big( \frac{\pi}{2} n \Big) u[n]
\end{align}

where

\begin{align}
u[n] &= \begin{cases}
1 & \mbox{if } n \geq 0 \\
0 & \mbox{else}
\end{cases}
\end{align}

and I'm supposed to find a difference equation for it. The problem is that I never got an advanced lecture on differential equation - not even one that introduces that topic.

Could somebody explain to me how to find a differential equation for a signal like $h_r[n]$ ?

Thank you.

Comment: It looks like you have a discrete signal. Did you mean difference equation?

Comment: What is $u[n]$?

Comment: @JimmyK4542 Oh sorry there was a translational mistake! Yes, I mean a difference equation I guess!

Comment: $u[n]$ should be the step function, i.e $u[n] = 1$ for $n \ge 0$ and $u[n] = 0$ for $n < 0$.

Comment: @mickep JimmyK4542 is right. I updated this to my question.

Comment: Have you learned Z-transforms yet?

Comment: @JimmyK4542 Yes, I understood it more or less. I can see that I will have to transform this to $H_r(z)$ which is 

\begin{align}
H_r(z) = \frac{rz}{z^2 + r^2}
\end{align}

and then perform some tricks to get where I want, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, take the Z-transform of $h[n]$. I'll let you work it out for yourself, but you'll get $H(z) = \displaystyle\sum_{n = -\infty}^{\infty}h[n]z^{-n} = \cdots = \dfrac{rz^{-1}}{1+r^2z^{-2}}$

Since $H(z) = \dfrac{rz^{-1}}{1+r^2z^{-2}}$, we have $(1+r^2z^{-2})H(z) = rz^{-1}$, i.e. $H(z) - r^2z^{-2}H(z) = rz^{-1}$.

Now, take the inverse Z-transform of each side. This will give you a difference equation.

The time shift property of Z-transforms will be useful, i.e. if $H(z)$ is the Z-transform of $h[n]$, then $z^{-n_0}H(z)$ is the Z-transform of $h[n-n_0]$.

Comment: Yeah, I made a mistake when I worked it out for myself. It is fixed now.

Comment: Think I got it! I should be able to solve it now, thank you!